# Unknown column 'unknown' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

When the user is logged in I am trying to find their information so I can display it to them, then I am going to allow them to update their information.

I keep getting an unknown column error, which is my session variable in the where clause but I am not sure why. The code below shows my query that I am using.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ". $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column `username` is a string typed, you should add a `'` for filtering, like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['login_user'] + "'";
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use a [`Prepared Statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with a placeholder for the `login` in your SQL and replace it with the value from the Session.

Another non-production-standard way is to enclose the login value in single quotes. Without the quotes, the SQL engine is thinking the login to be a column name.